# can't sign into admin of site i was asked to edit

Tags: php, admin

I was asked to help a friend fix a few small faults on her website. the person that built it years ago has been unreachable, but he had provided her with the ftp, host and pass. so i have no problem accessing the files. however, in order to make changes to the database, i'm having trouble signing in. I am not new to php, however I'm far from a professional developer, so i was looking for some help here.

all the database files include:

```
<?php include('../connect.php'); ?>
```

and when I go to the connect.php file this is what I see (names/passwords changed):

```
<?php // phpinfo(); ?>
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=blue;dbname=green','red','yellow');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

function brtonl($text){
  $text = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $text);
  $text = str_replace(array('<br>', '<br />'), "\n", $text);
  return $text;
}
?>
```

but 'red' and 'yellow' don't work. I get no error, it just returns the same popup asking for user and pass.

i looked into the .htaccess file which looks like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AuthName "Page d'administration"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /homez.312/green/.htpasswd 
Require valid-user
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but the .htpasswd file seems to point to a folder I can't see in the ftp. the only .htpasswd i see is in /admin/.htpasswd and it has names and codes that don't correspond with the connect.php, nor do they work when trying them.

can anyone let me know what might be the problem?
sorry for being such a novice.

Comment: Even accessing this file won't tell you much since .htpasswd is crypted anyway. You should ask the credentials to the administrator.

Comment: i thought so. The old administrator won't respond to messages unfortunately.